# How to retrieve data from a table using session id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can you help me with the codeignor?

```
$admin_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
```

Use this admin_id to get the roll_id from the user_table

[user_table ][1]

Can you tell me the query to take the roll_name in the roll_details table using this roll_id?

[role_details][2]

My Attempt

```
$admin_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_id'); 
$profile_info = $this->db->where('admin_id', $admin_id)
                     ->get('usertable')
                     ->row()
                     ->role_id
                   



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQaYO.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1wGt.jpg




I am getting roll_id

Can data be extracted from the roll_details table using that roll id?
```

Comment: Have you at least started to write the query and/or the PHP code to attempt to do this? If so, please show us

Comment: yes                                                                                                                     I am getting roll_id

Can data be extracted from the roll_details table using that roll id?

Comment: We would be able to read that if it was edited into the question

Comment: $admin_id = $this->session->userdata('admin_id'); 
$profile_info = $this->db->where('admin_id', $admin_id)
                     ->get('usertable')
                     ->row()
                     ->role_id
                 




I am getting roll_id

Can data be extracted from the roll_details table using that roll id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('role_details');
$this->db->join('user_table', 'user_table.roll_id = role_details.id');
$this->db->where('user_table.admin_id', $admin_id);

$query = $this->db->get();
$data = $query->result_array();
echo '<pre>';print_r($data);
```